# FragmentTransaction cannot resolve add()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Basically, I am trying to programmatically create fragments, that will display a list view reading from a database. I am following the [tutorial Programmatically Working with Android Fragments](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/programmatically-working-with-android-fragments/) to learn how to do such a thing, and I have come across an issue that I am having.
Android Studio cannot find the symbol add() when using a fragmentTransaction. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.morgan.dynamicnews;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}



public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
        case 4:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
            break;
        case 5:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section5);
            break;

    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}


public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    switch(position) {
        default:
        case 0:
            fragment = new FirstFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new SecondFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new ThirdFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new ForthFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new FifthFragment();
            break;
    }
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();
}


android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =            fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

fragmentTransaction.add();
}
```

Here is an Imgur upload of what is happening:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx2Fq.jpg

Comment: You are using wrong signature of `add`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 1**

You are using wrong signature of `add`.

[From documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.app.Fragment%29)

```
public abstract FragmentTransaction add (int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)
```

Add a fragment to the activity state. This fragment may optionally also have its view (if Fragment.onCreateView returns non-null) inserted into a container view of the activity. Calls add(int, Fragment, String) with a null tag.

*Parameters*

```
containerViewId     int

fragment            Fragment
```

So your code should be something like

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, new MyFragment()); // Change layout and Fragment class here
```

**Issue 2**

The whole code is outside of method and even the class which is not right. Move this code inside any method. Each line of code should be under any method (obviously variable declaration is could be anywhere inside class)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing two arguments.
The first is the id of the fragment placeholder and the second is the fragment itself.
It basically takes the same arguments as the replace call.

Answer (score 0):

`.add()` will take at least two arguments. [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int,%20android.app.Fragment))